# PHP code to call image Caption, Alternative Text, and Decription?

Tags: php, images, captions, description

Is there a Wordpress PHP code to call an image Caption, Alternative Text, and Decription? I have several images with Titles, captions, alt text and Description fields filled and would like to display these on the image.

I know how to call the image title:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

How to do so with the other fields?

Here's a sample of the rest of my code (this is for a slideshow)

```
<div class="slide">

    <?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, "slide_url_value", $single = true ) != "" ): ?>
    <a 
    href="<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, " slide_url_value ", $single = true ); ?>"
    title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-slide', array( 'title' => get_the_title() ) ); ?>
    </a>

    <?php else: ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'featured-slide', array( 'title'=>get_the_title() ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

</div>
```

Is there a way to use `<?php the_field(''); ?>` or id slugs?

Comment: You could try using `get_attachment_metadata()` - [View Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress stores image (attachment) data as follows:

- Description: `post_content` field
- Caption: `post_excerpt` field
- Alt: `_wp_attachment_image_alt` meta value

And in code, that translates to:

```
// Description
echo $post->post_content; // Raw
the_content();

// Caption (description as fallback)
the_excerpt();

// Caption (explicitly)
echo $post->post_excerpt; // Raw
if ( has_excerpt() ) {
    the_excerpt();
}

// Alt
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```